# I want to transfer data from text file to array

Tags: python

i'm new here and also new with programming with python
as an exercise i have  to read data (lat & lon) from a txt file with many rows and convert them into shapefile with QGIS

After reading i find a way to extract data into array, as step1, but i have soem issues..

I use the following code

```
X=[]
Y=[]
f = open('D:/test_data/test.txt','r')
for line in f:
   triplets=f.readline().split()  #error
X=X.append(triplets[0])
Y=Y.append(triplets[1])
f.close()
for i in X:
     print X[i]
```

with error:

```
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
```

Propably it's a warning for losing the rest rows but i really don't want them for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for line in f:` already iterates through the lines in the file, reading as it goes along. As such, it should be:

```
for line in f:
    triplets = line.split()
```

Alternatively, you could do as below, though I recommend the method above.

```
with open('D:/test_data/test.txt','r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for line in content:
        triplets = line.split()
        # append()
```

See [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in python for more info.

Also, `append()` does what it sounds like, so you don't need assignment.

```
X.append(triplets[0])  # not X=X.append(triplets[0)
```

Comment: this seems to work. now in my try to print what i read from 
i get the error:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str 
at last line where i try to print X[i]

i know that these are strings and have to convert at float but using
X.append(float(triplets[0])) give me the error:
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 49,24

Comment: @NasosGkimi `for i in X:` will directly iterate through the elements of `X`. That is, `i` is a string of `X`, not an index. As such, you can just `print(i)`

Comment: @NasosGkimi if you want to iterate using index - I don't really see the point here - you can use `for i in range(len(X))`, or `for i, elem in enumerate(X)`, where `i` is the index, and `elem` the corresponding string element.

Comment: @Ramon51. thanks for your answer.

Now my problem goes to amount of answers...
at my test file i have 10 lines... but program reads only 1..

any idea why this happend?

Comment: @NasosGkimi Yeah I noticed that before. Your `append` is outside the loop, so it will only execute once the loop is finished, and only on the last element. Moving it inside the loop should do the trick.

Comment: Ramon thanks a lot. 
I hope next time to came with more "serius" questions :)

Comment: My pleasure! We all have to start somewhere, just keep on coding :) On a side note, try using a debugger and/or a good IDE (I recommend PyCharm). You could've easily picked up on the missing `append`s and `i` being a string.

Answer (score 0):

`line` already is the line. Get the triplets by

```
triplets = line.split()
```

Comment: i make th change and i get a new error

typeError: 'str' object is not callable